# How to fix the navbar in the top of the page with docsify?

Tags: docsify

I read doc of docsify, it mentions that we can use `topMargin` to configure the space on top when scrolling the content page to reach the selected section. I try to use it to configure my page, but i failed to let navbar fix on the top of the page. it still scroll as the page goes up.

It mention that as we use `sticky-header` it is useful, but i wonder how to use `sticky-header`. It doesn't appear on the doc.

The doc goes here: [topMargin](https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=topmargin)